# Run a Python program which has invoked numpy with Python 3 in Sublime

Tags: macos, python-3.x, sublimetext3, anaconda

My computer is Mac. I have installed Anaconda in Sublime. When I run a Python program with Python 2, no error is given, but when I run it with Python 3, it shows:

> Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/test2_2.py", line 20, in 
>       import numpy as np
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: This is likely because the Python 3 distribution you're using (or calling) does not contain the `numpy` package, which you need possibly to install with `pip3` (or pip3.3, if for example you're using Python 3.3). I'm not sure what's installed when you install the Anaconda distribution, so maybe you should start from checking that.

Comment: I solve it now. I just installed Anaconda through the official website. And set the Python3.sublime-build path to the path of python3 in Anaconda. It work.Thank you.